# Cant delete original file and rename temp file

Tags: java, text-files, temporary-files

Im trying to delete the original file ("order2.txt") and rename the temp file to ("order2.txt") that I have store the new data. But for some reason the original could not be delete and it also cant rename the temp file. Anyone know what is wrong with my code and how can i fix it??

```
void editRecord(String editTerm){
        String tempFile="temp.txt";
        String file="order2.txt";

        File oldFile=new File(file);
        File newFile=new File(tempFile);
        String ID1="";
        String status1="";
        String food1="";
        String fq1="";
        String d1="";
        String dq1="";

        System.out.println("l");
        try{
            System.out.println("2");
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);
            Scanner x=new Scanner(new File(file));
            x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
            System.out.println("3");

            while(x.hasNext()){
                ID1=x.next();
                status1=x.next();
                food1=x.next();
                fq1=x.next();
                d1=x.next();
                dq1=x.next();
                System.out.println(dq1);
                String newStatus =statusTextField.getText();
                if(ID1.equals(editTerm))
                {

                    System.out.println(status1);

                    pw.println(ID1+","+newStatus+","+food1+","+fq1+","+d1+","+dq1);

                    System.out.println(ID1+","+newStatus+","+food1+","+fq1+","+d1+","+dq1);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(ID1+","+status1+","+food1+","+fq1+","+d1+","+dq1);
                    pw.println(ID1+","+status1+","+food1+","+fq1+","+d1+","+dq1);
                    System.out.println("y");
                } 
                System.out.println("t");
            }
            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("t");
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(file);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
            System.out.println("f");
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

            System.out.println("fail");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Print and show us the stacktrace for the exception.

Comment: A common reason for delete to fail (on Windows) is that some program has it open.  Possibly the program that is attempting the delete.   There is insufficient context in your question to know if that is what is happening here.

Comment: @StephenC it didnt show any exception

Comment: @Felipe, put `ex.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and use java.nio.file.Files to delete/rename.

Comment: @Mihe do i just need to import ```java.nio.file.Files```?

Comment: @Felipe, you also have to use the class :-) Like e. g. `Files.delete(oldFile.toPath());` instead of `oldFile.delete();`.

Comment: @Felipe - I said **Print** and show us the stacktrace ....

Comment: Also use the `Files.renameTo` file instead of `File.rename`.   The `Files` methods have the advantage that they throw an exception when they fail, so you can get some clues about the cause of the failure.   Exception messages and stacktraces are important and should not be discarded ...